# AttributeError when trying to place a label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a basic clicker game in Python using Tkinter. I am getting an `AttributeError` when trying to place a label that was created in another function from the same class (see code snip). The code running the tkinter window is **NOT** in the main thread, and the main thread is acting as the console. I am running `aClass.funcB` from the console, AFTER `aClass.funcA` has already executed.

```
class aClass:
    def funcA(self):
        self.aLabel = Label(top)
        global window
        window = self

    def funcB():
        global window
        self = window
        self.aLabel.place(<argsHere>)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<filePathHere>", line 334, in funcB
    self.aLabel.place(<argsHere>)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'aLabel'
```

If anyone wants to look at the actual code (that I dont understand parts of myself) please tell me.

**EDIT**: Here is a link to the github with the actual files https://github.com/LeotomasMC/Click-Clicker

**EDIT 2**: On a side note, if anyone could tell me how the window actually starts in this instance, that would be great

Comment: Where do you `__init__()` `self.aLabel`?

Comment: i added a link to the github with the actual thing. the file with this error is GameFiles/GUI.pyw on line near line 330

Comment: BTW: why do you use `global window` in class to send `self` ? You can use `self` directly or you use `self.window`

Comment: you assign `self` to global `window` and it seems you set `window = None` before you execute `funcB()`

Comment: i havent really figured out the `self` thing. i used a generater to make the inital window layout, and went from there, just copying and pasting and changing. the `funcA(self)` was generated with the `self` there, but i typed out `funcB()`

Comment: i set `window = None` before `funcA()` gets executed. if `funcA()` sets `window` to `self`, shouldnt be `None` after `funcA()` runs

Comment: if you don't create instance ie. `my_click = Click_Clicker()` and you always use `Click_Clicker.mainWindowLabels` instead of `my_click.mainWindowLabels` then `self` can be `None`

Comment: `Click_Clicker.mainWindowLabels` is a class with some strings in it. do you mean `Click_Clicker.__init__()`?

Comment: I mean everywhere - I see `Click_Clicker.update` and many other `Click_Clicker.something`

Comment: if you use `click_instance = Click_Clicker()` then you will have `self` in instance. And then you can use ie. `click_instance.update` instead of ` `Click_Clicker.update` - and you will have your window available as `self` in all methods - system will assign your window to `self` automatically and you will not have to use `global window`

Comment: where would i put `click_instance = Click_Clicker()`?

Comment: I see you already have `top = Click_Clicker(w)` in two functions so you don't have to use `click_instance = Click_Clicker()`

Comment: as for `self` - it is like `my` in real world`. You can say James Bond' car (`james_bond.car`) but Bond (inside his head) will say `my car` (self.car), you can say Batman's car (batman.car) but Batman (inside his head) will say `my carl` (self.car) too. Let Bond and Batman be instances of class hero - `james_bond = Hero()` and `batman = Hero()` so Hero inside all methods (like inside his head) can use `self` instead of `batman` or `james_bond`.

Comment: when i use top.<something> it just says that top is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove all the self as I think that it keeps it to only that def, because of that funcB doesn't know that aLabel exists.

Comment: i have another function that does the same thing with the `global window;self = window` that works

Answer (score 0):

Methods in Python classes need `self` as first argument:

```
def funcB(self):
    global window
    self = window
    self.aLabel.place(<argsHere>)
```

You need this argument to access `aLabel`.

Comment: when trying to do this i get `TypeError: funcB() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: How do you call `funcB()`?

Comment: i call `funcB()` from the console, the window is running in another thread.

Comment: You need an instance of `aClass` to call `funcB()`, or if you want call `funcB()` without an instance you can't use `self` inside.